# Pregunta básica sobre queues Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, queue

Acabo de terminar el proceso de colas y anda bien pero no como me imagine.

Cree la tabla job todo tal cuál la documentación de laravel.

En queue.php agregué el siguiente comando:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),
```

En el .env

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Llamo a la cola:

```
ProcesarImagenes::dispatch($galeria);
```

Y la utilizo normalmente:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $img = $this->galeria['imagenesGaleria'];
        $rut = $this->galeria['ruta'];
        //make recibe la imagen
        Image::make($img)
        ->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })
        ->save($rut);
    }
```

Ahora esto redimensiona la imagen perfecto. Pero en la tabla JOB no sucede nada, ejecuta el comando:

```
php artisan queue:work

[2020-12-07 18:12:47][4] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcesarImagenes
[2020-12-07 18:12:50][4] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcesarImagenes
```

Que me perdí?? de donde las está ejecutando? por que no hay registros en mi tabla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré en \bootstrap\cache\config.php

```
'queue' => 
array (
'default' => 'sync',
```

Por lo tanto realice el cambio a:

```
 'queue' => 
array (
'default' => 'database',
```

Y ejecute:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Esto resolvió mi problema.

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptadas tus respuestas